# Orphan removal in JPA 2 based on only one plain string

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence, jpa-2.0

I have the following situation:

```java
class Container {
    ...
    String key;
    ...
}

class Item {
    String containerKey;
}
```

I require a mechanism to automatically delete all items "referencing" containers, something like cascading.

Is there such a mechanism in JPA 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a JPA related solution, but what I did was to create a DB trigger. So every time when a record is deleted from the first table the deletion from the second one is triggered also.

Answer (score 2):

No, you'll have to get them all and delete them, or execute a delete query:

```
delete from Item i where i.containerKey = :containerKey
```